# Directed graphs and Compact Lie Groups

Tags: lie-groups

Is there a method for associating the edges and vertices of an arbitrary directed graph with the irreducible representations of a compact Lie group and the intertwiners
of the adjacent edge representations, respectively. In Physicists' terms is there a way to nterpret an arbitrary directed graph as a Penrose spin network

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question and there is a lot I could say on the topic. I suggest as a starting point you read the book:

Cvitanović, Predrag .
Group theory. Birdtracks, Lie's, and exceptional groups.
Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ,  2008.